# Combo Box que pinte un input

Tags: php, ajax, combobox

Tengo este código que contiene dos funciones y ambas funcionan lo unico que quiero es cambiar que en vez de que se muestren en un select que se muestren en un input type text readonly

El HTML que contiene el select que da formato a los combo box:

```
<td>
    <select class="form-control" name="acro_proyecto" id="acro_proyecto"  onchange="change_documento1();  change_documento2();" required>
            <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?> </option> 
            <?php
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
           $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
           $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select acro_proyecto from proyectos');
           $stmt->execute();
           while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
           echo '<option>' . $row['acro_proyecto'] . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Este es uno de los select que rellena el combo box

```
<th style="text-align:center;">Oferta/Proyecto</th>
   <td >
     <select  class="form-control" name="oferta_proyecto" id="oferta_proyecto" >
            <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('oferta_proyecto') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('oferta_proyecto') : ''; ?> </option>    
      </select>
  </td>
```

Este es el que aplica las funciones cuando se seleccione algo en el debe de realizar estas dos funciones:

Ajax:

```
function change_documento1()
        {
            var acro_proyecto = $("#acro_proyecto").val();
            var compania1 = $("#compania1").val();
            var acro_subcategoria = $("#acro_subcategoria").val();
            var acro_documento = $("#acro_documento").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "numdocumento.php",
                // fijate en el & para separar las variables
                data: "acro_proyecto=" + acro_proyecto + "&compania1=" + compania1 + "&acro_subcategoria=" + acro_subcategoria + "&acro_documento=" + acro_documento,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response)
                {
                    $("#num_documento").html(response);
                }
            });

        }

        function change_documento2()
        {
            var acro_proyecto = $("#acro_proyecto").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ofertaproyecto.php",
                data: "acro_proyecto=" + acro_proyecto,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response)
                {
                    //alert(response);return false;
                    $("#oferta_proyecto").html(response);
                }
            });

        }
```

Y estas llaman a otro archivo php como se ve, por ejemplo:

ofertaproyecto.php

```
 <?php

include('dbConfig.php');
$acro_proyecto = $_POST['acro_proyecto'];
$sql= "select oferta_proyecto from proyectos where acro_proyecto='$acro_proyecto'";
$query = $db->query($sql);

while($res = $query->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<option    value="'.$res['oferta_proyecto'].'">'.$res['oferta_proyecto'].'</option>'; 
}

?>
```

La estructura es la siguiente:

Todo el codigo html y las funciones ajax esta en un archivo llamado index.php y ofertaproyecto.php es un archivo distinto que realiza el combobox.

Se que tienen vulnerabilidades SQL pero como es por intranet y tenemos prisa por acabarlo nos han indicaod que lo hagamos asi y ya se modificara más adelante.

Comment: Que problemas has tenido ?

Comment: No se entiende bien si quieres los datos en un `input` o en un `select`. Si son varias filas lo normal es que los presentes en un `select`, no en un `input`... Por otra parte, en tu HTML no se ve que tengas un ¿`select` o `input` ? cuyo `id` sea `oferta_proyecto` al cual asignas la respuesta del script PHP: `$("#oferta_proyecto").html(response);` Por otra parte, tu consulta sigue siendo vulnerable de Inyección SQL.

Comment: lo estoy modificando poco a poco para ver si me explico mejor, se que es un poco lioso,sorry